# Output is wrong with IBM HPEL and logViewer.sh

Tags: hcl, was, wcs

I'm using a Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.12.
For the logging part of my application, I use Slf4j with Log4j. When HPEL is off, the logs are correctly stored in my SystemOut.log. However, when I switch HPEL on, I can see strange things using:

```
logViewer.sh -monitor 1
```

such as partial stack traces starting with a string like:

```
[1/6/22 1:35:18:737 CET] 00000864 SystemOut     O   [B@1e64eb40
```

Instead of the correct one I see with HPEL off:

```
[1/6/22 1:18:42:704 CET] 0000010b SystemOut     O [ERROR] (WebContainer : 0) myclass(mymethod:66) - my message
```

Also, I see blank new lines after every logged message, which I don't see with HPEL switched off. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue about partial logs specifying two JVM properties:

```
log4j.encoder.charBufferSize=32768
log4j.encoder.byteBufferSize=32768
```